# How to move files in Notepad++ to the left side?

Tags: notepad++

All the files I open in Notepad++ will pile up on the bar on the top. I need to move the files to be displayed on the left side. I once did it but I don't remember how I did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Notepad++, go to Settings --> Preferences.  Then, under "General", under "Tab Bar", select "Vertical".

[image]

If you want to have the filenames displayed horizontally, but still have the files displayed on the left side, you can try [the Window Manager Plugin](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=File:Scrsh_withWM.png)

Comment: I was actually looking for Document List Panel->Show. Thannks

Comment: @user1739812: Thanks for the followup to your question. The Document List Panel is exactly what I was looking for but it is "hidden" in Settings->General. I'd also suggest using the "Disable extension column".